# ASP.NET Treeview expand a paticular node after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have the requirement of showing directory structure in a treeview and the user should be able to add folder at any node on the treeview.

I have built up the tree structure and added new folder to the selected node. After adding new folder I rebind the treeview. My issue is that after rebind I need to show the currently created folder as selected node in the treeview.

aspx page:

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFolderName" runat="server" Text="Folder name" ForeColor="Gray"
        onblur="WaterMark(this, event);" onfocus="WaterMark(this, event);">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFolderName"
        ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="AddFolder"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddFolder" runat="server" Text="Add folder" OnClick="btnAddFolder_Click"
        ValidationGroup="AddFolder" />
</div>
<asp:TreeView ID="trvwDouments" runat="server" ExpandDepth="1" OnSelectedNodeChanged="trvwDouments_SelectedNodeChanged" 
    SelectedNodeStyle-BackColor="Silver">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Code to add new folder on 'Add folder click'

```
if (hdnDirPath.Value != string.Empty)
{
    string dirPath = hdnDirPath.Value + "\\" + txtFolderName.Text;
    DirectoryInfo newDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
        {
            newDirectory.Create();
            BindTreeview();
        }
        else
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Directory already exists!!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I need help to set the newly created node as the selected node.